# Javascript value output rewrite

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

Am retrieving a distance using distance calculator script using google maps etc...

Then calculating a fare cost based on that distance , but the output from that script displays dynamically from google as x,y miles in the distance field
using `document.getElementById("distance_road").value = distance1;`
and `distance1 = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text;`
In the 'cost' field data accepted and entered in this format (00.00) WHICH MEANS THE OUTPUT IS GIVING $NAN when trying to run the calculation..

Here is cost script

```
 function calculatefare() { /* variable declarations*/
   var subTotal=0.00;
    var pricePerFifthMile=0.54;
     var dropOffCharge=2.60;
      var overTwoPassengerCharge=0.50;
       var tripMilage=Number(document.getElementById("distance_road").value); 
       var passengers=Number(document.getElementById("passengers").value);
        /* if there are over 2 riders, each additional passenger pays $2 if (passengers>2)*/ { subTotal=overTwoPassengerCharge*(passengers-3+1); } 
        /* calculate the price based on miles in*/
         subTotal+=parseInt(tripMilage*5)*pricePerFifthMile; subTotal+=dropOffCharge; /* prints the price to the div. toFixed adds cents to integer calculations */
        document.getElementById('price').innerHTML=" $"+subTotal.toFixed(2); }
         // JavaScript Document
```

Is there any way to make this script accepts that format(read it) (xx,x miles)
or let say to clean this output to be xx.x  which means removing the ',' and 'miles'.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is to redefine the variable distance1, before getting outputed and called in the form. so the output will be parsed to define the desired output formatting. And that was possible only through defining the same function distance1 and not adding another function.

```
var distance1 = parseFloat(distance1.replace(",","."));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run two functions to achieve your goal, `replace` and `parseFloat`:

```
sanitizedDistance = parseFloat(distance1.replace(",","."));
```

The `replace` should convert your value to x.yy miles. And `parseFloat` should extract only the decimal value.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i tried  it in both scripts and it shows same output x,y miles and only NAN is gone and replaced with static data $0.0, also i replaced googleDistanceValue with distance1 variable but no luck..

Comment: can you give me an exact value that `distance1` has? (maybe inside quotes?)

Comment: Output image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzUZ5.jpg @ben You can post a comment with the link to image. There is no need to update the answer.

Comment: I've tried this in my chrome console and this is what I got:

`var numb = "18,4 miles";`

`undefined`

`var test = parseFloat(numb.replace(",","."));`

`undefined`

`test`

`18.4`

What is the difference between the value you are getting and my value "numb"?